# Allow user to choose file path where to save file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file

I am using `EPPlus` to create excel files and provide them with data.
And I want to allow user to select path and name for the file that will be created. File should be stored on client computer.

I have `RadTreeView` where I use `context menu`. I want to show `pop-up window`

```
<telerik:RadTreeView 
    runat="server" 
    ID="TreeViewUnit" 
    OnContextMenuItemClick="TreeViewUnit_OnContextMenuItemClick"
    meta:resourcekey="TreeViewUnitResource1">
    <DataBindings>
         <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding />
         </DataBindings>
         <ContextMenus>
         <telerik:RadTreeViewContextMenu runat="server" 
                    ID="cmTreeViewUnitContextMenu">
                     <Items>
                          <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Export" Value="Export"> 
                          </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                          <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Import" Value="Import">  
                          </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                      </Items>
          <CollapseAnimation Type="none"></CollapseAnimation>
       </telerik:RadTreeViewContextMenu>
                        </ContextMenus>
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

How can I do this? I am currently out of ideas =/
I checked `jquery` library but did not find anything, maybe I missed smth.

Comment: You cannot use an `OpenFileDialog` in ASP.NET. The file system of a client is  none of the server's business. Write the binaries to the response and let the user decide where to save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Browser security will not allow you to do this

If I understand you correctly what you're trying to do is to read client computer's folder structure and display it to your user so they'd be able to select a particular folder and name of the file.

Users are only able to select folder if they hit **Save file** when your file gets transferred because that selection is provided by the browser itself. But they may select **Open file** as well which may put the file in some temporary folder (Firefox and IE) or default downloads folder (Chrome). There's no way (for security reasons) that you'd be able to provide folder structure of client machine in your application that runs either on the server or the browser. And there's no way for you to control whether users will hit **Save** or **Open**.

It is only possible to ask users for file name. But that just means that your file is going to be transferred with that name, users can still rename it on save dialog.

#### Prevent browsers from opening Excel file directly within the browser?

Since you're transferring Excel files, you should be aware that they may open without any confirmation dialog directly within the browser (Internet Explorer) which bypasses the possibility of saving the file. You can prevent this on the sever side by setting particular mime-type as well as some other things to convince the browser to ask users what to do with the file.

[Refer to this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1597364/75642) to circumvent this *problem*.

Comment: But somehow people manage to provide file-path-browsing, question is how to do it even in another way.

Comment: what do you mean by *file path browsing*?

Comment: I got it) I wanted to allow user to choose location from server side but he is able to do it by himself. Thanks, I got it)